# Perl script with library function produces no output

Tags: bash, perl, html-entities, html-encode

I created this small little maintenance script to unescape HTML entities.

```
use HTML::Entities;

use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
    decode_entities($_);
}
```

The problem is, it produces no output when I pipe it through bash like so,

```
echo "&quot;a&quot;" | perl ../../tmp.pl
```

Comment: Why would you expect there to be? The function doesn't print anything, it just modifies `$_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see some output, you'd better `print`/`say` the return value:

```
use HTML::Entities;

use warnings;

while (<>) {
    print decode_entities($_);
}
```

Since in void context, the function modifies the string in-place, you could convert your script into a one-liner pretty easily:

```
perl -MHTML::Entities -pe 'decode_entities($_)'
```

Like a `while (<>)`, loop, the `-p` switch loops over each line of the input (either standard input, or the filename arguments), with the addition of a `print` in the `continue` block, which is run once at the end of each iteration of the loop.

Comment: wait, I can't believe I was *that* stupid, I completely forgot you needed to do that.